# Laravel Pest testing not returning summary of pass/fail tests

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, pestphp

During Pest test runs, we're unable to see a summary of passed and failed tests at the end. This issue is causing problems for our pipelines in GitLab, as they can't detect errors without exception messages being printed. Although we can manually identify failed tests by scrolling up and reviewing the console output.

```
Laravel 9.52.4
Pest 1.22.5
Pest laravel plugin 1.4.0
```

The current workaround is to enable stopOnFailure="true" option when running tests.